# How do I access the *remote* microphone in a RDP session?

Tags: audio, remote-desktop, microphone

I'm doing some remote testing of a system.  I have an external camera/mic as well as the built-in laptop camera/mic.  Using an Remote Desktop session, I can see into the lab, but I'd like to hear it too as my company's product is AV related.

Everything I've seen on the net is basically asking how to use the *local* mic in a RDP session, not how to use the *remote* mic in a RDP session.

Is there a way to use RPD to forward the audio from the mic to the remote speakers, or am I going to have to use some other SW?

Comment: You can do it via RDP if it shows up as a windows audio device. There are some steps to allow it though, as it's not enabled by default: https://serverspace.us/support/help/how-to-use-microphone-in-rdp-session

Comment: Hi @Cpt.Whale, sorry, I've seen this page before.  It states clearly at the end that `Click "OK" and connect to the remote desktop. Go to "Sound" in the "Recording" tab. And check for "Remote Audio".`  Which means that the remote computer is using the local computer's mic.  I want to use the remote computer's mic on the local computer.  I.e. the other way around.

Comment: @Adrian: Please comment on the answer.

Comment: Hi @harrymc.  Sorry.  Been really busy at work with other things.  Your answer is not what I was looking for.

Comment: I was trying to do this as well recently, can't believe this still hasn't been solved... There may actually be no non-hacky way to do this (ex. using a separate application over a separate port to forward the microphone over local net). Good luck in your quest.

Answer (score 0):

To listen to the remote audio:

1. On the local machine, make sure "Record from this computer" is not enabled
2. Connect to the remote machine
3. Open Sounds > Recording > (Microphone) > Properties > Listen
4. Enable "Listen to this device"
5. Set "Playback through this device:" to "Remote Audio" if it's not the default

[image: Listen to this device]

You may have to make sure audio redirection is enabled, (or at least not disabled) in the registry:

```
Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\
Name: fDisableAudioCapture
Type: REG_DWORD
Enabled: 0
Disabled: 1
```

This might also rely on the audio drivers to support it

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work.  I get to stop 3 and in the Recording tab there is no devices. Yet it's a laptop with an integrated and external webcam, so there must be a mic there.  I've also tried to set the reg entry to 0, but that doesn't do anything.  Though this looks like it should work. :(

Comment: I don't understand : You wish to bring the remote *microphone* to the local/client computer?

Comment: Yes @harrymc, that's is what I want.  That way I can hear the system I'm testing in that room.

Comment: Follow [this post](https://serverspace.io/support/help/how-to-use-microphone-in-rdp-session). If it works for you, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @harrymc, that's basically what @Cpt.Whale said.  No joy.   Just doesn't show any devices under the recording tab.  Says `No audio devices are installed`. Yet when I'm physically at the actual machine, there are 3 devices shown.  Maybe there's some permissions thing that is interfering?

Comment: It isn't the same, and should be done on both client and remote server.

Comment: @harrymc, ah, true enough.  Still, it didn't work. No recording devices were found.