# Access microphone of connected-to device while RDP session is active

Tags: windows-10, audio, remote-desktop, microphone

This was asked before [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1726327/how-do-i-access-the-remote-microphone-in-a-rdp-session), but not sufficiently answered.

I have a laptop in a room. This is the **remote device**. I use it to monitor some equipment. The laptop has an integrated webcam and microphone. When I am physically present and logged in at the remote device, things work fine:

- I can open the Windows 10 "Camera" app and see myself in the window that comes up.
- I can open audacity, select the microphone and record its audio. When I clap my hands, I see the spikes in the waveform.
- I can go to the Windows "Sounds" settings -> Recording -> right-click the microphone -> Properties -> Listen -> enable "Listen to this device" and then I can hear the recorded audio coming from the laptop's speakers.

I also have a laptop in a different room. This is the **local device**. When I go there, open RDP and connect to the **remote device**, I want to hear the microphone audio here too, but it does not work:

- Audio recording in Audacity "pauses". That is, Audacity still claims that it's recording, but the cursor is stuck in place.
- If I try to restart the recording, I get an error that Audacity can't open the device.
- In the Windows "Sounds" settings -> Recording, there is now either only a "Remoteaudio" device, or no devices at all, depending on the setting of the RDP connection -> Local Resources -> Remoteaudio -> Settings -> Remote audio recording. (Can be "Record from this computer" or "Do not record" respectively.)
- If I restart Audacity, I don't see the microphone as an input device anymore. If the "Remoteaudio" device is present, I can select that and try to record from it, but Audacity also "pauses" recording instantly.
- But: I can sill see the camera app working.

When I go back to the **remote device**, I can still hear the microphone audio coming from the speakers.

If I connect with Local Resources -> Remoteaudio -> Settings -> Remote audio playback -> Play on remote computer, then the audio devices on the **remote device** stay intact, but, of course, no audio will be relayed to the **local device**.

How can I hear the audio of the microphone of the **remote device** on the **local device**?

I also tried installing virtual audio cable, piping the microphone audio into the cable input and listening to the cable output, but the result is the same. The cable devices disappear upon connecting.

Comment: Damn, virtual audio cable was one idea I had... Sad to hear that didn't work. I can't find a way to do this either. It may be possible with a more hacky solution, but it seems this isn't something you can do with Windows natively, which is odd. Only thing I've found is there's a service that if you kill it stops the redirection of audio devices altogether (so no playback either :{ ) but then the whole RDP tunnel becomes unstable it seems. Side note, I tried multiple RDP clients: A Linux one, Android one, Windows 10/11 one, and old Windows 7 one, same issue whenever audio playback is enabled.